# Trying to sort repeater rows with this jQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I am trying to sort repeater rows with this jquery . But I am not able to save  sort items. Please help me . how can save sorting in database as well as in .aspx page?Thank you in advance

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$("#defaultList").sortable(); 

$(document).ready(function () {


    $("#defaultList").sortable(

    {
        update: function (ev, ui) {

            var result = $('#defaultList').sortable('toArray');
            updateSequenceNumber(result);
        }

    }


);

});


function updateSequenceNumber(items) {

    var originalIdAndSequenceNumber = '';
    var index = 0;

    for (i = 0; i <= items.length - 1; i++) {

        if (items[i].length == 0)
            continue;

        var item = $('#' + items[i])[0];

        originalIdAndSequenceNumber += item.attributes["originalId"].nodeValue + ":" + index.toString();
        originalIdAndSequenceNumber += "|";
        index = index + 1;
    }

    persistPositionUsingAjax(originalIdAndSequenceNumber);

}

function persistPositionUsingAjax(originalIdAndSequenceNumber) {

    $.ajax(

    {
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "text",
        url: "AjaxService.asmx/UpdateSequenceNumber",
        data: "s=" + originalIdAndSequenceNumber,
        success: function (response) {

        }
    }

    );

}
```

my ajax method:

```
[WebMethod]
public string UpdateSequenceNumber(string s)
{
    s = s.TrimEnd('|');
    string updateQuery = @"update dnn_Table_1 set SortId = {0}
        where ImageId = {1}";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    string[] originalIdAndSeqNumberArray = s.Split('|');

    foreach (var originalIdAndSeqNumberCombined in originalIdAndSeqNumberArray)
    {
        var tempArray = originalIdAndSeqNumberCombined.Split(':');
        int originalId = Convert.ToInt32(tempArray[0]);
        int sequenceNumber = Convert.ToInt32(tempArray[1]);

        sb.Append(String.Format(updateQuery, sequenceNumber, originalId));
        sb.Append(System.Environment.NewLine);
    }

    UpdateInDatabase(sb.ToString());

    return "Hello World";
}

private void UpdateInDatabase(string updateQuery)
{
    SqlDataProvider sqd = new SqlDataProvider();
    string ConnectionString = sqd.ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(updateQuery, conn);
    command.CommandText = updateQuery;

    conn.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    conn.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What status code does the ajax call return?

To me it looks like a 500. You are building an update statement that after a few iterations will look something like this

```
update dnn_Table_1 set SortId = 3 where ImageId = 2update dnn_Table_1 set SortId = 2 where ImageId = 4update dnn_Table_1 set SortId = 7 where ImageId = 6
```

That just won't work. Try eihter constructing the SQL update differently or move UpdateInDatabase into the foreach loop.

There might be other issues which I didn't spot, but this might be a starting point.

Hope that helps

Comment: http://highoncoding.com/Articles/513_Pimp_Up_List_Sorting_Using_JQuery.aspx . i refer this website . Please help me.

Comment: doh I didn't see the sb.Append(System.Environment.NewLine); bit and I was thinking MySql.

Just read the article you mentioned. Looks like it should work ok, but what is the actual response of the ajax code? Check with firebug or fiddler or something like that. Maybe something wrong with your connection.

Comment: You are declaring #defaultList as sortable twice. Remove the first one. Also, in hte ajax success function, put in an alert(response);

Comment: When i put alert(response); Its not sorting . i am getting a window .

Comment: The persistPositionUsingAjax function takes the long string and sends it to the server side method for the final persistence.Basically UpdateSequenceNumber takes apart the string and creates a long update T-SQL statement which is passed to the UpdateInDatabase metho